# Egit: how to make a reset of a subfolder?

Tags: eclipse, egit, git-reset

I want to make in EGit the same operation performed by the "Revert" command in Subversive on a single folder.

Basically, the expected result is a "reset --hard" of the chosen folder, removing all not committed changes, without make it for the other folders of the project.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it.

Select the folder you want to "reset", then right click -> "Replace with" -> "HEAD Revision"

Eclipse will ask you to confirm.

However, this doesn't remove untracked files (there is not the option as in subversive)